# Upgrading user passwords from salted SHA1 to bcrypt

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, sha1, bcrypt

I've been hired to rebuild a actively used application that was built on CodeIgniter 1.7.3 (on a PHP 4.2 server) using Laravel 4 on a new PHP 5.3 server.

The system has about ~500 users whose passwords are encrypted with a salted SHA-1 hash. I'd like to use bcrypt to increase the application's security as well as to integrate with Laravel 4's authentication system.

How would you suggest migrating these users passwords?

Comment: I believe there are a lot of 5.3.13 configurations out there so be sure the server is running at least 5.3.7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The whole point of a hash is that you can't recover the original password.

You have three options:

- Store bcrypt hashes of the SHA1 hashes, then SHA1 hash each password before bcrypting it on every login.
  *This may not be a good idea*.
- Upgrade each hash next time that user logs in. (so that you have the plain text to hash)
  *This is the best option, but you need to keep your SHA1 hashes and transition code until every single user logs in*
- Reset every user to a random bcrypted password and force them all to use Forgot Password to change it back.
  *You probably don't want to do this*

Comment: There is also third option, reset users passwords. It's not good option, but if you mentioned double hashing, you should also mention that.

Comment: @ElonThan: Yes; I just did.

Comment: Good points. Wasn't properly thinking about it before but option 2 makes sense.  I'll add a brcypt field to the user table and when a user logs in I'll bcrypt hash the password and store it in the new field, delete the SHA1 password from the record and add in some conditional logic to know which field to compare to until everyone is fully migrated.

Comment: @Nick: If you have a sizable userbase, it is likely to take a _long_ time to migrate everyone.

Comment: As SLaks said it might take a long time. Maybe it would be best to store an "algorithm" for each row which tells the system the algorithm to use and just update to bcrypt when they next login. This way you can change your algorithm later too and you shouldn't have to worry about going back and deleting your SHA column and messing up the data for some users.

Comment: @SLaks, what is the problem with the first option, you said it "May not be a good idea"

Comment: @SLaks, someone on #php freenode pointed me to this http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html to answer my own question

Answer (score 8):

- Add a column to your database that tells the system which hashing algorithm has been used
- On login, check the credentials as normal
- If they're using the old one and login is successful - bcrypt the password they entered and update their password and algorithm in the database.

Comment: Just realized this and commented on the first answer! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a random password for each user and send out a notification email to everyone with their new password. But this will result in confusion if a user doesn't see the email.

I recommend that you add another db field for the bcrypt value and then create an entry when a user logs in for the first time after the change. You can use either a separate field or delete the old hash to keep track.

When your active users have migrated, feel free to use the random password approach for the rest of your userbase to finish the migration.

Comment: Just realized this and commented on the first answer! Thanks for the help.